# C# pointer issue

Tags: c#, pointers, reference

Take a look at the following example:

```
public void inc(int num) {
   num++;
}

int a = 5;
inc(a);
```

In this case, `inc` won't increment the `a` variable itself. It is not pointing to the same location in the memory. In order to change `a`, I'll have to use `ref`.

However, in this example

```
public static void ExportSelectedRow(GridView gridView, object toObject, int skipCols)
{
    GridViewRow gridViewRow = gridView.SelectedRow;

    if (toObject is DataTable)
    {
        DataTable returnDt = (DataTable)toObject;
        GridViewColsToDatatable(gridView, returnDt, skipCols);
        DataRow dr = returnDt.NewRow();
        for (int i = skipCols; i < gridViewRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            dr[i - skipCols] = gridViewRow.Cells[i].Text;
        returnDt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    GridViewHelper.ExportSelectedRow(GridView1, dt, 1);
    ...
}
```

the selected row will be exported from the `GridView1` into `DataTable` although I didn't even referenced it in the function. So the `toObject` will be updated. It seems that

```
DataTable returnDt = (DataTable)toObject;
```

is actually referencing to the `toObject`. So my question, why in this example it is a reference, but in the first one, it is not?

Comment: Note that a 'ref' parameter value is really a typed reference to a field, local variable or array element--it is not a pointer.  Think of it as saying "changes to the variable in the called code should cause a change to the variable in the calling code."  It's abstracted from the underlying implementation of how the referencing occurs and it is more tightly constrained than a pointer (which could potentially refer to anywhere in memory, whereas a typed reference is highly restricted.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Contrary to what other people are going to say, by default *everything* (yes also reference types) in C# is passed by value. With `ref` or `out` they aren't.
But in the case of reference types, *the thing that is passed by value is a reference*.

`int` is of course a value type, `DataTable` is a reference type.

Comment: Upvoting you because you're the only one that is absolutely correct. Others, see http://www.mbaldinger.com/post/C-reference-types-are-passed-by-value!.aspx

Comment: Just to note, while this **is** correct, I also think that it would be very difficult for a beginner programmer to wrap his head around. Like pointers in classical languages this will take time to "get it". Hence I also think that a more elaborate (or simpler) explanation would also be good.

Comment: @Vilx yes, the concept of a reference to a reference (to an object) is definitely difficult for beginners to wrap their heads around, though good examples help with that.  I have run into FAR TOO MANY NON-BEGINNERS who are STILL confused by this, however, so it seems better to teach it properly from the start, even if it is difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 6):

C# has parameter types. Value Types (structs, enums, numbers, etc) and Reference Types (objects, strings, etc).

In your first example the value `5` is passed to the function, but in the second example `GridView1`'s reference is passed.

See MDN for a list of [value-types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [reference-types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which define how parameters are passed.

***EDIT***

**For a better definiton please see harold's answer.**

Comment: -1 Builtin or not has nothing to do with it, and only `ref` is pass-by-reference by the strict (and useful) definition. In the absence of `ref`, **value types** are copied, while for **reference types** only the reference is copied. Edit: Downvote removed as the edits removed the blatantly wrong stuff and added more accurate terms, although I still think it could be phrased *much* better (what's a "simple type" for starters?).

Comment: @Chad: value type and reference type are two different types of *data types* (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs(v=vs.80).aspx for details).  There are also different types of parameters: `ref` and `out` are two examples.  Note that `ref` can be applied to value-type parameters *or to reference-type parameters*.  The two concepts are independent. See @harold's answer which seems to be the only one to make this distinction correctly.

Answer (score 3):

`DataTable` is a reference type. `int` is a value type.

C# passes by value (unless `ref` or `out` is used).

- When you pass a `DataTable` to a method, you are actually passing a copy of the *reference*. Both references refer to the *same object*. Modifications to the object will be visible to the caller.
- When you pass an `int` you're passing a copy of the *value*.

If you use the `ref` keyword, it will pass by reference instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of ermm... types in .NET: Value types and reference types. The difference is exactly what you've demonstrated above.

Basically every `struct` is a value type and every `class` is a reference type. Basic types (like int, decimal, datetime, byte, etc.) are also implemented as structs, so they are value types. Well, actually, they're a bit special, but they are quite like structs.

MSDN has an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs(v=VS.100).aspx) about this, and the topic has been extensively covered in other places too. Just google for "value types vs reference types".

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is between a base type such as an int or double and an object.  When you pass an object you are passing a reference to it, while with intrinsic types yo are passing a copy of the value to the function.

structs are interesting in that they syntactically look like classes but are passed by value (copied) instead of by reference.